# Set cookie by including a js (by php) on IE

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, cookies

I included a javascript in my html page like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domaine.com/api.php"></script>
```

My api.php (on another domaine) return javascript code but before he set a cookie like that :

```
setcookie("mycookie", uniqid() , time()+2592000);
echo $javascript;
```

It works well on Firefox, Chrome... But on Internet explorer (8,9,10..) the cookie is not set !
Is is set when i call the api.php directly in my browser.

Comment: It works when they are on the same domaine ! How can i do ?

Comment: So you access the cookie on subdomain like sub.domaine.com? Try add this in the script: document.domain = "domaine.com".

Comment: I solved my problem by adding :

<?php header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); ?>

On my api.php file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably something to do with the way you include it?

Why link api.php using script tag?

```
<?php include_once('api.php'); ?>
```

Why not just include the php file in php rather than declaring it as javascript which can throw off some browsers.